# effect of reference of the literals on EQU

Tags: assembly

An assembler program contains the statement

```
X       EQU ,Y+25
```

how the EQU statement can be processed if

Y is a back reference
Y is a forward reference

Comment: The expression `Y+25` doesn't have to be evaluated at the point where you declare `X`. You haven't specified which assembler you're using, but the assembler could just save the string `"Y+25"` and replace every occurrence of `X` in the rest of the code with that string.

Comment: You mean to say that EQU statement can be processed for both the reference .?